# Getting error You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js

Could you please to help me to solve this issue, I am trying to render chart using chartjs in reactjs.
Here are my Codes:

file chart.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

export default class Chart extends Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: props.chartData
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.chartData))
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    displayTitle: true,
    displayLegend: true,
    legendPosition: 'right',
    location: 'City'
  }

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="chart">
        <Pie
          data={this.state.chartData}
          options={{
            title:{
              display:this.props.displayTitle,
              text:'Largest Cities In '+this.props.location,
              fontSize:25
            },
            legend:{
              display:this.props.displayLegend,
              position:this.props.legendPosition
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

home.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
import Chart from './chart.component';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // this.getchartData(); // this should be this.getChartData();
    this.getChartData();
    
  }

  getChartData() {
    // Ajax calls here
    this.setState({
      chartData: {
        labels: ['Boston', 'Worcester', 'Springfield', 'Lowell', 'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Population',
            data: [
              617594,
              181045,
              153060,
              106519,
              105162,
              95072
            ],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    });

    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} location="Massachusetts" legendPosition="bottom" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}
```

And Home component is used in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./App.css";

import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";

import Login from "./components/login.component";
import Register from "./components/register.component";
import Home from "./components/home.component";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      currentUser: undefined,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();

    if (user) {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: user,
      });
    }
  }

  logOut() {
    AuthService.logout();
  }

  render() {
    const { currentUser} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          </div>
          {currentUser ? (
            <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                  Welcome, {currentUser.username}
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={this.logOut}>
                  LogOut
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
          ) : (
              <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                    Login
                </Link>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item">
                  <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                    Sign Up
                </Link>
                </li>
              </div>
            )}
        </nav>

        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path={["/", "/login"]} component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

After login, it should redirect to home page.

My login code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-validation/build/form";
import Input from "react-validation/build/input";
import CheckButton from "react-validation/build/button";

import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";

const required = value => {
  if (!value) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This field is required!
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      password: "",
      loading: false,
      message: ""
    };
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangePassword(e) {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      message: "",
      loading: true
    });

    this.form.validateAll();

    if (this.checkBtn.context._errors.length === 0) {
      AuthService.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(
        () => {
          this.props.history.push("/home");
          window.location.reload();
        },
        error => {
          const resMessage =
            (error.response &&
              error.response.data &&
              error.response.data.message) ||
            error.message ||
            error.toString();

          this.setState({
            loading: false,
            message: resMessage
          });
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12">
        <div className="card card-container">
          <img
            src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
            alt="profile-img"
            className="profile-img-card"
          />

          <Form
            onSubmit={this.handleLogin}
            ref={c => {
              this.form = c;
            }}
          >
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="username"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <Input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                validations={[required]}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                disabled={this.state.loading}
              >
                {this.state.loading && (
                  <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span>
                )}
                <span>Login</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            {this.state.message && (
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {this.state.message}
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
            <CheckButton
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              ref={c => {
                this.checkBtn = c;
              }}
            />
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And I got error:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Regards with many thanks.

Comment: import Chart from './chart.component'; probably this line is wrong

Comment: Hi @Filipe, I don't think so because I can print out the json value in the chart.component.js means that Chart is successfully imported. If I commented the render path in chart.component, the error is gone

Comment: put the code where you call to the Home component

Comment: Hi @le123, added

Comment: Which component has the error?

Comment: Inside the render method in the chart component, if I comment that path the error is gone

Comment: I have solved this issue by downgrade the chartjs version in package.json "chart.js": "^2.6.0", "react-chartjs-2": "^2.1.0"